# SNMP Query IP Listening Ports

Tags: snmp, nagios

I would like to SNMP-query remote hosts for their listening ports.

Using snmpwalk shows this:

```
# snmpwalk -c public -v2c somehost TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4
TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4."0.0.0.0".13 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4."0.0.0.0".22 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4."0.0.0.0".111 = Gauge32: 0
...
```

But I fail to query for particular ports (as the monitoring software - nagios - would do):

```
# snmpget -c public -v2c localhost TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4.\"0.0.0.0\".111
TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4."0.0.0.0".111 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

I tried to place some particular shell-protection but without success:

```
# snmpget -c public -v2c localhost 'TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4."0.0.0.0".111'
TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4."0.0.0.0".111 = No Such Instance currently exists at 

# snmpget -c public -v2c localhost 'TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4.\"0.0.0.0\".111'
TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4.\"0.0.0.0\".111: Unknown Object Identifier (Index out of range: \"0 (tcpListenerLocalAddress))
```

Can anybody shed some light on this and may have a hint how to query properly for this OIDs?

Comment: Please note: This is on Debian with packages snmp(5.7.2~dfsg-8.1+b1) and snmpd(5.7.2~dfsg-8.1+b1)

Comment: Add the output of snmpwalk -c public -v2c somehost -On TCP-MIB::tcpListenerProcess.ipv4

Comment: .1.3.6.1.2.1.6.20.1.4.1.4.0.0.0.0.13 = Gauge32: 0
    .1.3.6.1.2.1.6.20.1.4.1.4.0.0.0.0.22 = Gauge32: 0
    .1.3.6.1.2.1.6.20.1.4.1.4.0.0.0.0.37 = Gauge32: 0

Comment: So.... 111 was the socket for the current snmpwalk then? And the 2nd time, it came up as 37 instead of 111? You should use numeric OIDs with Nagios anyway, but I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: Well, my posting was bogus. I simply posted the first three lines of snmpwalk output without verifying that it matches the above. Consider the "37" being a "111" ;) Besides that, your suggestion is of course valid. I tried to be "smart" by using the MIB representation, but obviously net-snmp has still a problem with parsing that. Thanks for your support.